# Add Chevron Image to Tab on Mobile Size

Tags: css, tabs

I am trying to make a 3-tab layout using CSS that is responsive. I have two issues. The first is the third tab won't line up with the box. It's just a tad bit off.

[image: picture of my third tab not lining up]

The second issue is I would like to show chevron images on mobile screens (up to close, down to expand). I am not sure how to do this.

Here is my HTML.

```
<section class="tabs-wrapper">
            <div class="tabs-container">
                <div class="tabs-block">
                    <div class="tabs">
                        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked="checked" />
                        <label class="label1" for="tab1"><!--<span class="material-icons">favorite_border</span>-->
                            QuickBooks for
                            Manufacturing &amp; Distribution</label>
                        <div class="tab">
                            <!-- <h2>Angular</h2> -->
                            <div class="flex-container">
                                <div class="tab-list-item-left">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Monitor and track inventory.</li>
                                        <li>Create bills of material and work orders.</li>
                                        <li>Set up accurate COGS and inventory costing system.</li>
                                        <li>Assist in inventory assembly setup and implementation.</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-list-item-right">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Capture indirect and direct costs.</li>
                                        <li>Build sales order reports.</li>
                                        <li>Track profit and loss.</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
                        <label class="label2" for="tab2"><!-- <span class="material-icons">face</span>--> QuickBooks for
                            Professional
                            Services</label>
                        <div class="tab tab-2">
                            <!-- <h2>React</h2> -->
                            <div class="flex-container">
                                <div class="tab-list-item-left">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Track time and expenses.</li>
                                        <li>Set up separate billing rates and customized invoices.</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-list-item-right">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Analyze profitability by project or client.</li>
                                        <li>Process payroll.</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
                        <label class="label3" for="tab3"><!--<span class="material-icons">lightbulb</span>--> QuickBooks
                            for
                            E-Commerce</label>
                        <div class="tab tab-3">
                            <!-- <h2>Vue</h2> -->
                            <div class="flex-container">
                                <div class="tab-list-item-left">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Set up client-specific reports to track financial data.</li>
                                        <li>Bill clients.</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-list-item-right">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Manage inventory.</li>
                                        <li>Create profit and loss reports.</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Now, here is my CSS.

```
/**
 * Reset
 */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.15;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: #1a1a1a;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

p,
ol,
ul,
li,
dl,
dt,
dd,
blockquote,
figure,
fieldset,
form,
legend,
textarea,
pre,
iframe,
hr,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

/**
 * Global Rules
 */
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #0d0d0d;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
}

a,
a:visited {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #0067b8;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  border-bottom: none;
  outline: 0;
}

a:focus {
  border-bottom: none;
  outline: thin dotted;
}

a img {
  border: 0;
}

/**
 * Tabs Container
 */
.tabs-container {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

/**
 * Tabs Block
 */
.tabs-block {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/**
 * Tabs
 */
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs label {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 0.079rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*background-color: #000;*/
  color: #000;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  transition: background-color ease 0.3s;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.label1 {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.label2 {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.tabs .label3 {
  background-color: #cecece;
  padding-left: 51px;
  padding-right: 41px;
}

.tabs label .material-icons {
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}

.tabs .tab {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
  /*color: #000;*/
  background-color: #fff;
  /*box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}

.tabs .tab-2 {
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.tabs .tab-3 {
  background-color: #cecece;
}

.tabs .tab > *:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.tabs [type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs [type="radio"]:checked + label {
  /*background-color: #fff;*/
  color: #283841;
  /*border-top: 4px solid #0067b8; */
  /*box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);*/
}

.tabs [type="radio"]:checked + label + .tab {
  display: block;
}
@media (min-width: 770px) {
  body {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
  }

  .tabs-container {
    padding: 4rem 4rem;
  }

  .tabs label {
    order: 1;
    width: auto;
  }

  .tabs .tab {
    order: 9;
  }

  .tabs [type="radio"]:checked + label {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .tabs {
    width: 800px;
  }
}

ul {
  list-style-image: url("https://wordpress-833610-3044148.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Icons-87-18x16-1.png");
}

li {
  padding: 0.5em;
  margin: 1px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.tab-list-item-left {
  padding: 3px;
  flex: 50%;
}

.tab-list-item-right {
  padding: 3px;
  flex: 50%;
}
```

Can someone walk me through how to add the chevron images when viewing on a mobile screen?